# Oracle sql like multiple conditions with select from other table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 375 dialcodes in table "temp":

```
917277
917278
918083
...
9172738
```

I can do the following:

```
select * from cdr where 
dnis like 917277% or
dnis like 917278% or
dnis like 918083% or
...
dnis like 9172738%
```

Is it possible to make a query including "select in" and "like %" conditions?

```
select * from cdr where dnis in (select dialcode% from temp)
```

Comment: no..you can't do that

Comment: Is dialcode a char/varchar column or numeric?

Comment: can't you just use `SELECT * FROM cdr WHERE dnis1 AND dnis2 LIKE %search%` or `SELECT * FROM cdr WHERE dnis1 OR dnis2 LIKE %search%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to use `exists`:

```
select c.*
from cdr c
where exists (select 1 from temp t where c.dnis like dialcode || '%' );
```

Note that this does not require `distinct`, even when there might be multiple matches.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JOIN` and `LIKE` to achieve similiar result:

```
SELECT c.*           -- DISTINCT may be needed if dialcodes overlap each other
FROM cdr c
JOIN temp t
  ON c.dnis LIKE t.dialcode || '%'
```